# Android App Getting error in logging in

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm getting error after pressing log-in button with correct credentials. The dbconnection is properly set and the php API is working. I tried it on a web browser.

Here is the java code:

```
package com.example.test;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.capstone.istudyUser.SProfile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.42.59/test/login.php";


    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iUsername);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iPassword);

        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RStudent);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLogin:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.RStudent:

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
        * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        * */
        boolean failure = false;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
           pDialog.show();
       }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
           int success;
           String username = user.getText().toString();
           String password = pass.getText().toString();
           try {
               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

               Log.d("request!", "starting");
               // getting product details by making HTTP request
               JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                      LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

               // check your log for json response
               Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

               // json success tag
               success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
               if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
               }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;

        }
        /**
        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
           // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
           pDialog.dismiss();
           if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

       }

    }



}
```

I wonder what's wrong with my program :(

Here is the log cat:
http://pastebin.com/wzXzCShH

Comment: Post your logcat output to see the exception you get.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in LogCat? Did you try to debug it?
If you're trying to use an emulator it might not have access to the same network as your computer. Emulators have their own network.

Comment: I've already tried to debug it but i can't really figured out. What's wrong with the program. I'm not using an emulator. I'm using my phone with the same LAN on my computer.

Comment: Just edited my post and added the log cat.

Comment: Is your URL working? Have you given it permission to access the internet in your Android Manifest? It seems to be being caused by a Null Pointer when you make the HTTP request because the connection is refused.

Comment: @TomRichard, Thank you! I just forgot to add permission >.< it's now working. Thank you!

Comment: @DandeloDarkyCardona I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as solved. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have given the app the INTERNET permission in your Android manifest. You are being denied permission to access the URL which is then causing a NullPointer and causing your application to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the NullPointer execption is likely being caused by not having requested the Internet permission.

Add the below line to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

You should be able to avoid the force close even if it fails by adding an additional catch block like this:

```
} catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException npe){
    npe.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will allow your app to continue gracefully. (This is a good thing to have as it will cover you when your php script is b0rked for example and so returns no valid JSON string, or the url is unreachable for some reason like device being in airplane mode or network being down)

Answer (score 0):

@Dandelo Darky Cardona - make sure that your ip address is accessing the localhost, try to type you ip address in you browser and check if it isn't giving you permission denied or not
because i had the this errors before and it droves me crazy, until i knew that the problem in the ip address.